# Axios turns nested JSON array to empty when posting

Tags: javascript, json, axios, geojson

I'm trying to post data from Axios to my API but although my json data looks correct when passing to Axios, browser tools tells me that my nested property is empty.

My data contains nested objects and looks like this:

```
{
  'name': 'foo',
  'index': 1,
  'nested': [
     { 
       'date': '2020-05-10',
       'geojson_data': { 
         'crs': Object,
         'name': 'my-name',
         'type': 'FeatureCollection',
         'features': [{ ... }, { ... }]
        }
     },
  ]
}
```

**Edit**: `geojson_data` results from parsing .geojson file, thus, the `features` array contains ~300 items.

My axios function is defined here:

```js
async post(data) {
    console.log(data);
    return axios
      .post(API_URL + 'endpoint/', 
      data,
      {
        headers: authHeader()
      })
      .then(response => {
        return response.data;
      })
  }
```

`authHeader()` is used to provide Bearer token authorization.

I check that data passed to axios is correct (looks like above), but browser tools tell me that data actually sent looks like

```
{"name":"foo","index":1,"nested":[]}
```

Why is my array empty ?

**Edit**: I tried to manually populate a sample nested object and it seems to work. Yet, whenever I use my actual data, it doesn't.
Don't know if it's relevant but in the console, here is the difference I can see between the 2 collapsed objects (actual vs sample):

- Sample : `Object { name: "foo", index: "1", nested: (1) […] }`
- Actual : `Object { name: "foo", index: "1", nested: [] }`

Notice the `nested` array which looks like it is empty. Yet, if I expand it, they look the same. Any ideas ?

P.S: looks like [this SO post](https://%7B%22name%22:%22OLPM%22,%22index%22:%229%22,%22dated_profiles%22:[]%7D) from 3 years ago, but without solution

Comment: If I post my data with Postman, it works well, any chances there is an issue on Axios side ?

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with the fact that `data` is created within async loop. I'm waiting for it to finish but there must be something wrong on this side. Yet I don't understand why the console prints an empty array when the object is collapsed and the actual object when expanded.